# c++: a map with keys being map

Tags: c++, functional-programming

I am new and c++ and I wish to ask whether there exists some data structure like functional in mathematics (a function with domains being function and range being something else):

```
map<map,int>
```

Comment: C++ is a general purpose language that facilitates the building of abstractions. If your problem can be phrased as a computing problem, then you can implement a solution in C++.

Comment: C++11 has anonymous lambda expressions.

Comment: actually, I am using a MIP package called Gurobi and it forced me to use c++98.... Thank you all very much:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [std::map](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/) template requires the `Key`  to be an ordered type. But `std::map` are not themselves ordered by default, you have to define some order yourself.

[C++11](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B11) has also [std::functional](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/functional/) and [anonymous functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anonymous_function), i.e. lambda expressions.

Perhaps you could have

```
typedef std::map<int,int> first_order_map_t;
// you have to implement:
bool operator <(const first_order_map_t&, const first_order_map_t&); 
// then you could use
typedef std::map<first_order_map_t,int> second_order_map_t;
```

Remember that `std::map`, like every data structure in a computer, is a *finite* map. The set of actually bound keys is finite!

I am not sure that such approach is efficient. Read some recent [Stroustrup book](http://www.stroustrup.com/books.html), e.g. [a Tour of C++](http://www.stroustrup.com/Tour.html).

Comment: Oh.... I see:) That's brilliant, thank you:) I will surely up vote you if I have enough points:)